# ASP.NET-MVC serve files in a directory as if they were in root

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET-MVC5 project, the client is a Single Page Application written in AngularJS (only static files needed to launch it, C# Controllers don't serve HTML, they only process AJAX calls). For convenience, all the static files for the Angular part (.html, .js, .css) are in the `WebClient` directory located in the root.

Everything works fine with paths like `www.my-app.com/webclient/index.html`, but I would like it to work with just `www.my-app.com/index.html`. For that I would somehow need to map the `WebClient` directory to the root address. What is the best way to do this? Preferably, with just `Web.config` file (but any working way is welcome).

P.S. I know that I can write my own controller to do this, but, as far as I understand, it will be slower than built in StaticFileHandler. I'm trying to find a better solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so, as always, the guaranteed way to encounter the answer in the next 5 minutes is to finally ask the question on SO.

The answer is IIS URL Rewrite Module. Found the info on it [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

You need to add this to your Web.config (the regexp still needs some work to shield the API route and add all possible symbols)

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Route root to WebClient" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([_0-9a-z-./\?]+)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="WebClient/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```